# Mobx observale value is null when used in useEffect hook

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks, next.js, mobx

I am trying to get userdata from firestore based on uid obtained from authStatechanged in mobx. But when i try to access it in useEffect, it shows value is undefined but if i print its value in body it shows after slight delay. What should i fo to get that value in useeffect.

```
index.js

 useEffect(() => {
      setposts(props.posts);
    authUser && setuser(authUser) ; //it shows authuser is null
    
    }, []);

  return (
   
 <Layout>
     
 {authUser && authUser.uid}  //it gives correct value after delay

</Layout>


store.js

class Store {

  @observable authUser = null


  constructor(){
       
        const result = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(authUser => { 

        if(authUser){
          this.authUser = authUser
        }
       })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`firebase.auth()` is asynchronous function, so when you component is rendered first time `authUser` is `null`. After some time this call gets resolved with user, then `onAuthStateChanged` is called and you set the user. But your `useEffect` is already got called and since you specified empty array `[]` as effect dependency it does not get called again.

You can use second effect like this, for example:

```
 useEffect(() => {
      authUser && setuser(authUser);
    }, [authUser]);
```

Every time `authUser` changes this effect will be called.

But at the same time I am not quite understand why you need to `setuser` anyway, you can use it right away since it is stored inside your Store.